# Can I Cancel a Stop Order with Vanguard

Tags: stocks, selling

I have a few stocks in a Vanguard acct.  I want to place Stop Orders on them (sell them if the market goes to pot).  Just curious, If I place a stop order, with a sell price at xyz, for 60 days, can I cancel it prior to that 60 days if I choose?

Comment: If it hasn't been executed, sure. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

Contingent orders (limit, stop loss, all or none, GTC, etc.) can be adjusted or cancelled at any time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer as mentioned above, yes you can cancel it.  Thx

Comment: Rather than add your own answer, please accept the other answer. This gives the answerer a bit of reputation and tells people with the same question in future which the most useful answer is.

Comment: Also, "mentioned above" depends on the sort order of answers, so what's above for you can be below for others. And new answers can end up in between. There's a "share" link on each answer that you can use to link directly to that answer. (But as Rupert says, in this case you should mark the correct answer)